# Eliminate "e_sqlite3.dll" during single file compilation

Tags: .net, sqlite, .net-core, f#, microsoft.data.sqlite

In my attempts to compile a single-file binary that leverages [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite), I am consistently left with ***two files*** that are both required for the application to work.

1. `{ProjectName}.exe`
2. `e_sqlite3.dll`

Is it possible to include the `e_sqlite3.dll` into the exe?

> It appears that [System.Data.Sqlite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.Sqlite) exhibits the same behaviour, but instead a file called `SQLite.Interop.dll`.

## Sample code

> Note: I realize there is no actual interop with SQLite happening, this code is purely meant to demonstrate the compilation.

#### ProjectName.fsproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" version="7.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

#### Program.fs

```ml
module ProjectName.Program

open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main (argv : string[]) =
    printfn "Hello world"
    0
```

Compiling the project as follows:

```
dotnet publish .\ProjectName.fsproj -c Release
```

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

It turns out that it's rather easy to do this in net6, net7 and (presumably) beyond, by setting `IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract` to `true`.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>

    <!-- Must include this line -->
    <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
    <DebuggerSupport>false</DebuggerSupport>
    <EnableUnsafeUTF7Encoding>false</EnableUnsafeUTF7Encoding>
    <HttpActivityPropagationSupport>false</HttpActivityPropagationSupport>
    <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
    <UseNativeHttpHandler>true</UseNativeHttpHandler>
    <UseSystemResourceKeys>true</UseSystemResourceKeys>
    <EnableCompressionInSingleFile>true</EnableCompressionInSingleFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" version="7.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```